# Finite Sum and Infinite Series Sum

Tags: sequences-and-series

I've come across this set of problems.

> **(i)** Show that $\frac{1}{2r-1}-\frac{1}{2r-5} \equiv \frac{6}{(2r-1)(2r+5)}$.
> Hence find
> **(ii)** $\sum_{r=2}^{30}\frac{6}{(2r-1)(2r+5)}$, giving your answers to 3 decimal places.
> **(iii)** $\sum_{r=2}^{\infty}\frac{6}{(2r-1)(2r+5)}$, giving your answer as a single fraction.

The first one is trivial. The second one I separated the summation into two summations as the first part would indicate me to do. However, after this, I am confused. The answer scheme simply states $0.629$ without explanation, which is very frustrating as I could simply put it into a calculator to get such an answer. I tried writing the first few sums out as $r = n$, $r=n+1$ etc. to see if the sum telescopes but had no luck doing so.

For the second part, the answer scheme also simply states $\frac{71}{105}$. I have an inkling this has something to do with geometric series, though I'm not sure as I have not studied that yet.

Comment: Putting $r=r+3$ you'll see some sort of telescoping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $T_r=\frac{6}{(2r-1)(2r+5)}=\frac{1}{2r-1}-\frac{1}{2r+5}$

Let $V_r=\frac{1}{2r+5}$

$\Rightarrow T_r=V_{r-3}-V_r$

$$\Rightarrow\sum_{r=2}^{30}\frac{6}{(2r-1)(2r+5)}=\sum_{r=2}^{30}T_r=T_2+T_3+T_4+\ldots+T_{30}$$

$T_2=\color{blue}{V_{-1}}-\color{red}{V_2}$

$T_3=\color{blue}{V_0}-\color{red}{V_3}$

$T_4=\color{blue}{V_{1}}-V_4$

$T_5=\color{red}{V_2}-V_5$

$T_6=\color{red}{V_3}-V_6$

$$\Rightarrow T_2+T_3+T_4+T_5=\color{blue}{V_{-1}}+\color{blue}{V_{0}}+\color{blue}{V_{1}}-V_{\color{red}{3}}-V_{\color{red}{4}}-V_{\color{red}{5}}$$

$$\Rightarrow T_2+T_3+T_4+T_5+T_6=\color{blue}{V_{-1}}+\color{blue}{V_{0}}+\color{blue}{V_{1}}-V_{\color{red}{4}}-V_{\color{red}{5}}-V_{\color{red}{6}}$$

Now you can clearly observe the pattern. Therefore,

$$\color{black}{\Rightarrow \sum_{r=2}^{n}T_r=V_{-1}+V_{0}+V_{1}-V_{n-2}-V_{n-1}-V_{n}}$$ where $V_n=\frac{1}{2n+5}$

Now you can solve both the parts by substituting the value of $n$.